# Could not execute JDBC batch update:Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException:

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am new to hibernate programming Please help me out, I have problem while executing the below  files.I am using MySQL Database. My error is

> SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
>       SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
>       SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
>       Hibernate: insert into UserDetails (userName) values (?)
>       Hibernate: insert into UserDetails (userName) values (?)
>       Hibernate: insert into UserDetails (userName) values (?)
>       Hibernate: insert into vehicle (vehiName) values (?)
>       Hibernate: insert into vehicle (vehiName) values (?)
>       Hibernate: insert into UserDetails_vehicle (UserDetails_userID, vehi_vehiID) values (?, ?)
>       Hibernate: insert into UserDetails_vehicle (UserDetails_userID, vehi_vehiID) values (?, ?)
>       Hibernate: insert into UserDetails_vehicle (UserDetails_userID, vehi_vehiID) values (?, ?)
>
> Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
>       at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:96)
>       at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
>       at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:275)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:268)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:188)
>       at                                          org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
>       at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
>       at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1216)
>       at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:383)
>       at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:133)
>       at com.annt.java.UserTest.main(UserTest.java:34)
>       Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'vehi_vehiID'
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(PreparedStatement.java:1669)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatch(PreparedStatement.java:1085)
>       at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70)
>       at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268)
>       ... 8 more

### UserDetails.java

```
@Entity
public class UserDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int userID;
    @OneToMany
    private List<vehicle> vehi = new ArrayList<vehicle>();

    public List<vehicle> getVehi() {
        return vehi;
    }

    public void setVehi(List<vehicle> vehi) {
        this.vehi = vehi;
    }

    public int getUserID() {
        return userID;
    }

    public void setUserID(int userID) {
        this.userID = userID;
    }
    private String userName;

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

}
```

### vehicle.java

```
 @Entity
    public class vehicle {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private int vehiID;

        public int getVehiID() {
            return vehiID;
        }

        public void setVehiID(int vehiID) {
            this.vehiID = vehiID;
        }

        public String getVehiName() {
            return vehiName;
        }

        public void setVehiName(String vehiName) {
            this.vehiName = vehiName;
        }
        private String vehiName;

    }
```

### usertest.java

```
public class UserTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        vehicle veh1 = new vehicle();
        veh1.setVehiName("car");
        vehicle veh2 = new vehicle();
        veh2.setVehiName("bus");
        UserDetails user1 = new UserDetails();
        UserDetails user2 = new UserDetails();
        user1.setUserName("user2");
        user2.setUserName("user2");
        UserDetails user3 = new UserDetails();
        user3.setUserName("user3");
        user1.getVehi().add(veh1);
        user2.getVehi().add(veh2);
        user3.getVehi().add(veh1);
        SessionFactory sf = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session ss = sf.openSession();
        ss.beginTransaction();
        ss.save(user1);
        ss.save(user2);
        ss.save(user3);
        ss.save(veh1);
        ss.save(veh2);
        ss.getTransaction().commit();
        ss.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: "*Duplicate entry '1' for key 'vehi_vehiID'*" - you are inserting the same primary key value twice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message is quite clear: there is a unique key violation constraint: you're inserting the same vehicle for two different users:

```
user1.getVehi().add(veh1);
//...
user3.getVehi().add(veh1);
```

That is incorrect, since the association between User and Vehicle is a OneToMany association. A given Vehicle thus belongs to one and only one User. If you want to share a vehicle between users, then you need a ManyToMany association, and you need to remove the unique constraint on `UserDetails_vehicle.vehi_vehiID` on (Hibernate won't create it if you use it to generate the schema)

Answer (score 0):

You're affecting veh1 to 2 differents users, so you need a Many2Many association, not a One2Many :

`@OneToMany

private List vehi=new ArrayList();`

Many2Many : One User can be affected to Many Vehicules And One Vehicule can be affected to Many Users
One2Many : One User can be affected to Many Vehicules, but One Vehicule can be only owned by one User

That's why you got an integrity exception

Answer (score 0):

The object values must be different while doing relation ship
 give the different value in user3.getVehi().add(veh1)